# LibreOffice Base Execute Stored Procedure/Function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, libreoffice-base

I'm busy setting up a odb file with LibreOffice Base to be used with LibreOffice Calc. The odb file is working fine I can create and save regular queries but it is giving an error when I try to execute a Stored Procedure/Function. When using pgAdmin I can execute the call just fine

```
select * from funcProduction(current_date, current_date);
```

This works and returns the data expected but when I try in LibreCalc Base using Queries > Create Query in SQL View, executing the exact same call to the Stored Procedure/Function it fails with an error

```
Syntax error in SQL statement
```

I'm not sure why there's an error or even where to find what the error is

Answer (score 1):

Set the query to [Run SQL command directly](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Run_SQL_command_directly).  This is best for any engine except HSQLDB 1.8.

Related:

- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/133467/base-andor-syntax-w-mysql/?answer=133476#post-id-133476
- [sql dialect in OpenOffice Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770466/sql-dialect-in-openoffice-base/9315951#9315951)
- https://superuser.com/a/899223/541756

Comment: I hopefully don't want to set it to run directly though because then you can't pass parameters